# Devops & Bitbucket Build Pipeline - not enough space on the disk

Tags: .net, git, azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm trying to build Azure devops pipeline which connected with project uploaded to Bitbucket repository, but each build I faced these 3 errors

Error MSB3491: Could not write lines to file "obj\Release\XXX.txt". There is not enough space on the disk.

Error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "D:\a\1\s\XX\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll" to "bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll". There is not enough space on the disk.

Error MSB3027: Could not copy "D:\a\1\s\XXX\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll" to "bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

How can I know where is the problem (Devops or Bitbucket) and how to fix it.

Comment: Hi, Maybe you could share your repo size here.

Comment: Disk drive prices recently shot up due to demand inside China, but even at $800 for a 16TB drive (vs $500 before this spike) it's about $50/TB or five cents a gigabyte. Spend a few dollars, perhaps, and you should have plenty of storage. :-) (Note: I have no idea what azure-devops charges per GB, but a quick google search suggests $.50/GB. Wow, they're raking it in there...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#capabilities-and-limitations),

> (Microsoft-hosted agents) Provide at least 10 GB of storage **for your source and build outputs**.

So, if you are getting "not enough space in disk error" it might mean that **the amount of disk space used by your source code** (files, repos, branches, etc), **together with the amount of disk space taken by your build output** (files generated as a result of the build process) **is crossing the 10 GB** of storaged provided by your DevOps plan.

Workaround, you could try to split your repo.